# Abrir um PDF no Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

Estou tentando criar um link para abrir um PDF no Intel XDK.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('pdf/arquivo.pdf', '_blank');">
```

Porém ele abre o navegador e fica apenas na tela em branco.
Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score -1):

Cara, eu tive muitos problemas com o XDK para abrir arquivos XLS, o que você precisa é usar um plugin de terceiros (na aba de projetos você tem como adicionar plugins do seu computador). Ele sozinho não consegue abrir os arquivos.

https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer

Esse aqui aparentemente funciona, vou usar ele também então se der certo aqui eu posto o código!